# Do we have a notion of $G-$module where $G$ is only a group without a ring structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

Do we have a notion of $G-$module where $G$ is only a group without a ring structure ? If yes what do we call it and where do we use it. but if not why we are interested in $R-$modules where $R$ is a ring and not in $G-$modules where $G$ is only a group?

Comment: Given any group $G,$ there is a ring $\mathbb Z[G],$ and any $\mathbb Z[G]-$module can be called a $G$-module.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Does this only work for finite groups or for infinite aswell? I mean then you could construct something like $\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z]$ and I am not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring

Comment: $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z]$ can be seen as equivalent to $\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} a_iz^i$ where the $a_i$ are integers and only finitely many $a_i\neq 0.$

Comment: But of course you can (equivalently) define a $G$-module without defining the group ring, namely as an abelian group endowed with an action of $G$ by group automorphisms. The group ring is here to notably show that the language of modules over rings however encompasses such a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, called a [$G$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module) as you expected!

The category $\bf{G-Mod}$ of (left) $G$ modules can be identified with the category of (left) $Z[G]$-modules, i.e. with the modules over the group ring $Z[G]$, so this is secretly still an $R$-module for a ring $R$. Maybe this explains why these aren't talked about so often.

Comment: (This stems from the fact that abelian groups and $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are the same things.)